# Call 'onClick' Code every time the page loads

Tags: javascript, php

I have some php/html that creates a dynamic table with a set of links.  When the link is clicked it loads a page $url1 and called a function called 'update' which makes a mysql call.

I am removing the table and modifying the mysql to return a single row. **I want the code to 1)load the linked page ($url1) 2)run the update function that is called by onclick.**

**Original Table**

```
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>        
            <td><a href="<?php echo $url1; ?>" target="_blank" class="url" onclick="update('<?php echo $row['node']; ?>');"/>Run</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['level1_text']." - ".$row['level2_text']." - ".$row['level3_text']." - ".$row['level4_text'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['last_run_date']; ?><input type="text" class="node" value="<?php echo $row['node']; ?>" hidden></td>
            <td id="cnt"><?php echo $row['run_count']; //$idate=explode(" ",$row['insertdate']); $bdate=explode("-",$idate[0]); echo $bdate[2]."-".$bdate[1]."-".$bdate[0];  ?></td>
        </tr>
```

I started with the 'update' function, i figured I could reduce the sql statement to return only 1 row and call the update function with this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">update('<?php echo $row['node']; ?>');</script>
```

That doesn't seem to work so I further simplified the code for testing but my update function is not being called.

```
<script type="text/javascript">update('525');</script>
```

Any pointers?  Is there a good way call this function on page load and then load the page at $url?

Comment: It looks like you are mixing Javascript and PHP much too tightly. What language is `update()` written in? PHP or Javascript? I bet this is a function running on server using PHP for you can "make a _mysql_ call" only in context of server, not the browser. It looks like you are missing some glue code (XHR) in method `update()` to be written in Javascript that is requesting server using XHR to perform the actual query to MySQL written in PHP.

Comment: @cepharum - I think you are right...

Here is the update()

     function update(node){
 $.ajax({
   type : 'POST',
   url : 'updateData.php',
   data : {
    node : node
   }, 
   success : function(data){
    //alert(data);
    window.location.reload(); 
   }
  });
}

</script>

The  updateData.php that is called makes a mysql connection and runs a query.

Comment: Well, this update() is triggering reload of document and I hope this won't interfere with your initial intention to trigger this method each time the page is loaded (resulting in an infinite loop). Aside from that: is your code working by now?